USB 3.0 SS lines issue
Can you route USB 3.0 SS lines to two PCB's but the USB controller is located on the second PCB?
The PC host is connected to the first PCB over a usb c-c connection (center usb port in image). Then these high speed lines are routed on this first PCB B1 from 1 connector to a pair of second connectors. (Both are in parallel to each other which might be the source of issues?)
Only one of these second connectors is connected over usb c to usb c to another board B2 which has the USB 3 peripherals and the controller.
The problem is that when connecting the host directly to B2, we get a usb 3 connection but when we connect to B1 and then B2, we are facing issues.
Impedance has been set to 100Ohms on this PCB B1 according to the requirement of the USB 3 controller. This is a 6 layer PCB with FR4 improved used as the prepeg material. I have rechecked impedance which seems to be inside the tolerance.
Signals have been also been length matched.
Any advice on this matter?


You might want to explain what issues you are getting. In addition to what you are trying to achieve with the SS lines is impossible, there may be other issues as well which make the Type-C interface not to work as a whole. So what else is wrong would be seen in the schematics.

When making boards, it is important to follow the specifications for the protocols you are trying to transfer.
USB 3.0 is a high speed protocol, it samples at a fast rate. You want to avoid stubs and use muxes/redrivers if you really have to split or conditionally forward a signal, your board has neither. Each fork in the signal on your board is going to cause a reflection to be send back to the transmiter and each path has only half the signal strength. Your stub is then going to reflect the signals back, causing mangled signals when they come back to the fork. Keep the total length of all stubs on the same superspeed transmissions line between redrivers below 1cm
Your schematic also shows that you use USB C to C cables, yet your board does not show any signs of a mux used to handle the 2 different connector orientations. This makes your board refuse to work in certain orientations of the cable.
Another bigger mistake is that you connected the transmit pins of the cables together, the namings of the SS pins are from the device side, it always sends a signal on the TX1/TX2 and always received from the RX1/RX2 (the superspeed pairs are flipped inside the cable)
For handling the super speed things, you need to go back to the drawing board and use muxes controlled by a micro controller to switch between the inputs. (you can likely read the signal from the USB C controller you use for power detection, since USB C is by default vbus dead) For example if it detects port B1 has a flipped cable and port B2 has a normal orientation cable, it needs to configure the muxes to pass B1 RX1 to B2 TX2, B1 RX2 to B2 TX2, B2 RX1 to B1 TX2 and B2 RX2 to B1 RX1, redriving the signal to keep the signal to noise ratio down enough.

The answer is no, you can't make a T piece which splits a high speed interface into two connectors like that.
Not even if the other connector is unused. The high speed signals experience a impedance mismatch at the point where it splits into two. First you have a 100 ohm transmission line and it turns into two 100 ohm transmission lines - the impedance of driving two 100 ohm transmission lines in parallel is now 50 ohms. On high speed transnission lines, you avoid even short stubs, and by intentionally splitting you introduce a very long stub.
As the end of the unused port is unterminated, any signals will see again an impedance mismatch and the signal will just reflect back from the unterminated end.
High speed here means the USB3 is either 5 Gbps or 10 Gbps on a single lane.
And the secondary issue is that USB uses 90 ohms impedance, not 100 ohms. Generally for lower losses, the impedance used on PCB is even less than 90 ohms.
